# Woocommerce Subscriptions Payment Gateway Price Update Issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal-subscriptions

I have an issue with a website that runs WordPress and Woocommerce.  It offer subscriptions on physical products and from time to time we need to adjust the subscription price upwards to cover cost increases from our suppliers. we are using the Woo Subscriptions extension and have done Bulk update subscription prices. The customers are being sent an email a week before their subscription renews telling them about the price increase and giving them the option to not renew. When the subscription renews woocommerce charges the new price, and the order emails all show the new price however PayPal still charges the customer the old price.

We followed the WooCommerce Instructions from here https://woocommerce.com/document/automatewoo/examples/subscription-workflows/bulk-update-subscription-prices/ We where expecting customers to be chgarged the increased price in both WooCommerce and in PayPal. WooCommerce did charge the new price, buty PayPal did not.

Comment: You should report that problem to WooCommerce Subscriptions support page, opening a ticket.